# How to always show the attachement field in Outlook 2010/2013?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, pdf, adobe-acrobat, microsoft-outlook-2013

We will switch from Office 2003 to Office 2013 very soon.

Unfortunately, it loses one extremely important functionality: If you open a multiple page PDF with Acrobat Standard (or Professional), you can select one page and drop it in the attachment field, and you will see you pages in the attachment field.

In Outlook 2003, this field is always there.

But, in Outlook 2013, the field is **not** shown. If you want the same functionality, you have to click on the “Attach file” button, select a file, erase the file in the “Attachment” field AND drag & drop the wanted page in the field. This procedure is too long and just annoying for me.

And no, you cannot drag and drop a PDF page from Acrobat to the "body" field; you have to drop it to the attachment field.

This issue is very disturbing for me.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: If you drag a file to the body so that the Attachment field shows up, can you then drag pages into it from Adobe?

Comment: No; the field appear, but we have to erase the file in the field first, and drag and drop the wanted pages after that.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible to make Outlook always show the field.

Here's a possibly shorter work-around - use your desktop as a proxy. :)

Select the page(s) that you were going to drag to the email, but instead, drag them to the desktop.

An "untitled extract pages.pdf" file will be created.

Drag that file to the email.

If you leave the file on your desktop, the next time you drag page(s) to the desktop it'll overwrite it, so you don't have to delete it each time.

[Source](http://forums.adobe.com/message/3919223#3919223)